# Triple integral of $E$ inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + (z-3)^2 = 9$ and above the half cone $z = 2 - (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$.

Tags: integration

So I have to do a triple integral of $E$ inside the sphere
$x^2 + y^2 + (z-3)^2 = 9$ and above the half cone
$z = 2 - (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$.

I don't know what bounds to use since the sphere isn't centered to the origin and the cone isn't either.

I have to use spherical coordinates.

Comment: You could start by doing a change of variables to center it at the origin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the following change of variables (spherical coordinates)

$ x = \rho \sin \theta \cos \phi $

$ y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi $

$ z = 3 + \rho \cos \theta $

where $\rho \in [0, 3] $.

Now we we want

$ z \ge 2 - \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2} $

Therefore, we want

$ 3 + \rho \cos \theta \ge 2 - \rho \sin \theta $

So that

$ \rho  \cos(\theta -\dfrac{\pi}{4} ) \ge -\sqrt{2} $

For $ \theta \in [ 0 , \dfrac{3\pi}{4} ] $, this is automatically satisfied.

For $ \theta \in [ \dfrac{3\pi}{4} , \pi]$ ,

$ \rho \le -\dfrac{\sqrt{2} }{\cos (\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{4} )} $

Let's see when this upper limit is equal to $3$

$\cos( \theta - \dfrac{\pi}{4} ) = - \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} $

Gives $\theta = 2.8471 $

While $ \dfrac{3\pi}{4} =2.35619 $

Hence the integral now is as follows

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
 I &= \displaystyle \left(\int_{\phi = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta = 0}^{2.8471} \int_{\rho = 0}^3 f(\phi, \theta, \rho) \rho^2 \sin(\theta) d\rho d\theta d\phi\right) \\
&+\left(\int_{\phi = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta = 2.8471}^{\pi} \int_{\rho = 0}^{g(\theta) } f(\phi, \theta, \rho) \rho^2 \sin(\theta) d\rho d\theta d\phi\right) \end{split}\end{equation} $

where $g(\theta) = \dfrac{-\sqrt{2}}{\cos(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}) } $